# Not able retrieve web or list using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery

I have added the below code, But I am not able to retrieve the web or  site. And added this script in Content editor web part of list. Can you please let me know where did I go wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(ctl00_ctl34_g_9308082e_bd1c_4559_868d_9aa8eb1da6aa_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_checkNames).attr("onclick", "ValidateForm()");
});

function ValidateForm() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var vars = url.split("=");
    var ID = vars[1].split("&");
    var ID1 = ID[0];
    alert(ID1);
    var context = new SP.ClientContext("http://siteName");
    alert(context);
    var web = context.get_web();
    alert(web);
    alert
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    alert(list);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type ='Text'>" + ID1 + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    listitem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    alert(camlQuery);
    alert(listitem);
    context.load(listitem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailed));

}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    var ListEnumerator = listitem.getEnumerator();
    while (ListEnumerator.moverNext()) {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var id = currentItem.get_item("ID");
        alert(id);
    }
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("error");
}
```

Comment: Use F12 developer tools > Console and reload the page to see what error message(s) you get.

Answer (score 0):

My test code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ValidateForm,"sp.js");

function ValidateForm(){
var url = window.location.href;
    var vars = url.split("=");
    var ID = vars[1].split("&");
    var ID1 = ID[0];
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://sitename");
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("list name");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type ='Counter'>" + ID1 + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, onFail));
    function onSuccess(){
        var itemArray = [];
        var ListEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var id = currentItem.get_item("ID");
        alert(id);
     }
        
    }
    function onFail(sender,args){
    alert(args.get_message());
    }
}

</script>
```

**You error:**
[image]
And you jQuery selector should be wrong.

jQuery selector documentation for your reference:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/